# Plotting rows of different dataframes in R

Tags: for-loop, plot

I have just started using R and this might be a very basic thing, but here is my problem:
I am trying to use a for loop to plot the first row and mean of the remaining rows for different dataframes, each one having its own plot.
I first stored all my table names
    `files <- c("file1, "file2", "file3"...)`

Then I tried using a for loop to plot it
    `for(i in files) {plot(c(1:13), i[1,])}`

```
                    X    T     C    A  C.1  A.1   A.2     G   T.1  T.2   A.3  G.1   A.4
sample1            NA -0.6  10.6 13.7 -4.7  5.6 -11.7 -13.8 -11.9 -6.4 -12.7  2.9   7.5
sample2           3.4 -1.5  -1.3 11.9 10.3  8.0  -8.0  -9.9   6.5 -0.5   3.4 -4.5   4.8
sample3           0.8 -5.7   3.9 20.3 14.0  8.1  -8.0  -9.8   5.9 -6.7   6.5 -3.9   9.0
sample4          15.9 -6.1  -5.8 14.8 22.4 15.4  -2.8  -9.4   9.4 -4.2  -0.8  1.5   4.5
```

And that is where I am having trouble. I can plot it if I use the name of my file instead of i[1,], but I have many files. Each table looks like the following, but with more rows and columns.
Also, does anyone know how to change the x axis so that instead of numbers and can assign a nucleotide letter to each position ? (X, T, C, A, C, A, A, G, T, T, A, G, A)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get(i)` in order to refer to the object with the name given by `i`.

For example:

```
for (i in files) {
  plot(1:ncol(get(i)), get(i)[1, ], xaxt='n')
  axis(1, at=1:ncol(get(i)), labels=colnames(get(i)))
}
```

The default x-axis is suppressed with `xaxt='n'`, and then plotted with `axis(1, ...)`. To allow the code to generalise to `data.frames` with varying number of columns, I've used `1:ncol(get(i))`, which returns a sequence of integers from 1 to the number of columns of the object with name `i`.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for the help. That was giving me a lot of headache